# How to accelerate Inverse[] for positive definite matrices symbolically?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, inverse

I am trying to construct a positive definite matrix based on the multiquadric radial basis function (RBF) for a set of thirteen points symbolically in order to later approximate the Laplacian operator as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
$Assumptions = {c > 0, h > 0, r > 0};
phi[r_] := Simplify@Sqrt[c^2 + r^2];
f2[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := Sqrt[c^2 + (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2];
(*Laplacian operator*)
f3[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
  Simplify@D[f2[x1, x2, y1, y2], {x1, 2}] + 
   Simplify@D[f2[x1, x2, y1, y2], {y1, 2}];
f3[x1, x2, y1, y2];

(*A set of thirteen points*)
pts = {{x1, y1}, {x1 - h, y1}, {x1 + h, y1}, {x1, y1 - h}, {x1, 
    y1 + h}, {x1 - h, y1 - h}, {x1 - h, y1 + h}, {x1 + h, 
    y1 - h}, {x1 + h, y1 + h}, {x1 + 2 h, y1}, {x1 - 2 h, y1}, {x1, 
    y1 + 2 h}, {x1, y1 - 2 h}};
maxs = Length[pts];

(*Constructing a distance matrix*)
dm0 = Table[
   EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], pts[[j]]], {i, maxs}, {j, maxs}];
dm = dm0;
(*Constructing the positive definite matrix based on the RBF*)
A3 = Simplify@phi[dm];
A3 // MatrixForm;
A4 = Transpose[A3];
```

The point is, it is impossible in my system to compute the inverse of the matrix $A4$ due to its size when I use `Inverse[]` function directly! Since, I finally want to compute the action of this matrix inverse on a vector, I thought maybe it is better to use the Taylor expansion of each $A4$ entries up to 8th order (lower orders may not be useful). Thus, I come up with the following:

```
vec1 = FullSimplify@Table[
    f3[x1, x2, y1, y2] /. Thread[
      {x2 -> pts[[1, 1]], x1 -> pts[[j, 1]],
       y2 -> pts[[1, 2]], y1 -> pts[[j, 2]]}
      ], {j, maxs}];
vec1 // MatrixForm;

A4 = Table[Normal@Series[A4[[i, j]], {h, 0, 8}], {i, maxs}, {j, maxs}];
sol = Simplify@(Inverse[A4].vec1);
```

This is super slow which is also due to the use of `Simplify` function. I finally want to compute the following where I fail:

```
taylororder = 2;
Normal@Series[sol, {h, 0, taylororder}]
```

I am grateful if someone could drop some hints or comments to accelerate the process of computing the `Inverse[]` or `Simplify[]` for such a symbolic task. I even thought of using matrix functions such as `sol3 = (MatrixFunction[#^-1 &, A4].vec1);`, but again failed since it demands so much computing time.

Comment: You simply cannot do general matrix operations on symbolic matrices. Nearly all algorithms rest on diagonalizaton,  working fast on numbers, but building towers of nonsolvable algebraic equations in general. Keep in mind, that only equations up to 4. powers are solvalbe in terms of finite root expression, higher powers are symbolically represented by their roots objects, that is the job defered  to be done once numbers are supplied.

Comment: (1) It might be faster to instantiate for specific values of the points rather than to attempt a symbolic solution.

Comment: (2) For inverse-times-vector maybe the characteristic polynomial form of inverse will help. If dimension is 13 it amounts to 13 matrix-times-vector and vector additions. This might be useful if a symbolic method is absolutely required.

Comment: Yes, since a symbolic answer is indeed required, I must find a way out of this. I think the symmetric feature of the final solution `sol` might help. Because, the structure of the solution is like this `{sol[[1]],sol[[2]],sol[[2]],sol[[2]],sol[[2]],sol[[6]],sol[[6]],sol[[6]],sol[[6]],sol[[10]],,sol[[10]],sol[[10]],sol[[10]]}`.